# Getting the maximum of array, sort() vs reduce()

Tags: javascript

Assume we have some array and I want to get the maximum of the elements.

```
array.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0]
```

and

```
array.reduce((a, b) => (a > b) ? a : b)
```

will both return the maximum.

The question is, which one is preferred?

For a specific case of my project, I could be iterating over 100+ elements, 100+ times which I thought would be big enough to matter for the small performance difference.

Comment: I think array.reduce is faster. Sorting always needs more operations behind

Comment: I would prefer `Math.max(...arr)` myself

Comment: reduce is O(n), sort is O(nlogn).

Comment: One approach is just to profile them for your use-case.  Another approach is to consider how these alternatives scale - in terms of big-O notation.

Comment: @KarlReid What if the array is *array of objects*? This is my case and I eliminated the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_apply) for that reason.

Comment: @KarlReid Math.max is not recommended for large array.

Comment: @NinaScholz I didn't know that. Sounds like reduce is the winner then. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

array.reduce seems faster..

```js
var numbers = [];


function myFunction(item) {
 for (var i = 0 ; i<100000 ; i++)
 {
   numbers.push(i); 
 }


 var t0 = performance.now();
 var x = numbers.reduce((a, b) => (a > b) ? a : b);
 var t1 = performance.now()
 document.getElementById("timex").innerHTML = (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds";
 
 var t2 = performance.now();
 var y = numbers.sort((a, b) => b - a)[0];
 var t3 = performance.now();
 
 document.getElementById("timey").innerHTML = (t3 - t2) + " milliseconds";
 document.getElementById("reduce").innerHTML = x
 document.getElementById("sort").innerHTML = y
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get the highest numbers in the array.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p>Highest number (array.reduce): <span id="reduce"></span>  time taken : <span id="timex"></span></p>
<p>Highest number(array.sort): <span id="sort"></span> time taken:<span id="timey"></p>


<script>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pointers, its always better to use `jsPerf` for performance related stuff. They loop automatically based on few criteria to even test cached values. Second, instead of `for(...) { numbers.push(i) }`, you can try `var numbers = Array.from({length: 100000}. (x,i) => i)`, if you wish to use ES6 methods

Comment: @Rajesh sure, I will look into it. It is good to learn a new thing every day.

Comment: @priyadarshiswain Glad I could help. You can refer [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-sort-for-maximum) comparison and/or add in your answer for readers.

Comment: Also I just realized, `var numbers = [10000];` is not doing anything. Here `10000` will be replaced in loop. So you can ignore this part. Just set it to blank array.

Comment: @Rajesh I used that to check if the logic was indeed returning largest number for a lesser loop count. I Should have removed it in the final code.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to check performance and this is [result](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/353980), hope you know more about them.

[image]