# Function to find highest value from an array of values, not using `Math.max()`

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, max

I want to create function that will find highest/maximum value from an array of values.
For example: `numbers = [2, 24, 48, 9, 15, 41]`.
How can it be done other than using `Math.max()`?

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome!
I'm assuming JavaScript and added that to question's tags.
Change if not.
Thank you and good luck!

Comment: You can iterate over the array values by `for` loop, `forEach`, `reduce`...

Comment: You'd need to compare to previously stored values, so, I'd set the initial max variable to `-Infinity`.

Comment: Thought exercise: How would you do this in your head/on paper?

Comment: *"I need to find another way"*: so it is homework. You should show your efforts.

Comment: @trincot, so what if it's homework?
I agree: should show efforts.

Comment: About `-Infinity`: either that, or set initial max variable to first value of array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function maxVal(array){
    let indexOfMax = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] > array[indexOfMax]){
            indexOfMax = i;
        }
    }
    return array[indexOfMax];
}
```

Comment: Nice!
Why not store the max value directly?
(array can be empty = problem for your code, but it is not asked for explicitly by asker).

Comment: @iAmOren it is another possibility. I thought that this person might also find it useful in another situation to return the index, so I wanted them to have it at hand.

Comment: Good thinking!
The asker should show attempts and not let us guess nor do the work...

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Array.prototype.reduce`, it's usually the smartest way for doing simple math operations like getting averages, ranges or min-max

```js
function max(...values) {
  return values.reduce((prev, curr) => curr > prev ? curr : prev)
}
// or without the `...rest` parameter to use an array directly
function maxFromArr(values) {
  return values.reduce((prev, curr) => curr > prev ? curr : prev)
}
```

with this you have some clean and efficient code:

```js
max(1, 2, 3, 8, 435, 32, 0) // => 432
// or for an array
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 72, 32, 0]
maxFromArray(arr) // => 74
// or
max(...arr) // => 74
```

#### Common Pitfall

**When comparing numbers, usually always test for a positive (`is` instead of `isNot`)**

Testing for a positive result (`is the current larger ? use current`, instead of `is the current smaller ? use previous`) will also automatically take care of any item that can't be turned into a proper number (comparing a number to `NaN` will always return false. eg. `12 < NaN` and `12 > NaN` both return false).

If you do it the other way around you might get a surprising result:
(feel free to run this snippet in any playground)

```js
function max (...values: number[]) {
  return values.reduce((prev, curr) => curr > prev ? curr : prev)
}

function naïveMax (...values: number[]) {
  // notice were testing for a negativ: is the current smaller ?
  // if it **isn't**, use the current
  return values.reduce((prev, curr) => curr < prev ? prev : curr)
}

const arr1 = [1, 21, 3, 12, 2]
console.log(max(...arr1)) // => 21
console.log(naïveMax(...arr1)) // => 21
// looking good so far

const arr2 = [89, -21, 32, {}, 342]
console.log(max(...arr2)) // => 342
console.log(naïveMax(...arr2)) // => 242
// looks still ok, despite an object being mixed in, but

const arr3 = [64, 2, 3, 95, 32, {}]
console.log(max(...arr3)) // => 95
console.log(naïveMax(...arr3)) // => {}
// whoops, the largest number suddenly is the object
```

here's `min` for completeness sake

```js
function min(...values) {
  // again, test for a positive to filter `NaN`-values
  return values.reduce((prev, curr) => curr < prev ? curr : prev)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getHighest = numbers.sort((a, b) => b-a)[0];
```

Comment: It does work and it does answer the question, the selected answer uses reduce, it is faster:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47509585/getting-the-maximum-of-array-sort-vs-reduce